# OS X DNS queries failing with a custom tun interface

Tags: firewall, netstat

I have a slightly modified version of tun/tap for OS X 10.10.5 running.  The interface is brought up by a small python script which reads from `/dev/tun` and then forwards all requests over an adhoc connection. When the interface is brought up I manually set the IP to `10.0.0.1` subnet mask: `255.255.255.0` and DNS: `8.8.8.8`.  However whenever I try to perform a DNS request it tells me the connection times out, and I never see the DNS queries sent out in WireShark.  My goal is to route all traffic through `/dev/tun` but can't figure out why DNS is not working.  Here are my current routes:

```
$ netstat -r
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.0.0.1           UGSc            3        0    tun0
default            link#6             UCSI            2        0     en0
10.0.0.1           10.0.0.1           UHr             5        2    tun0
17.155.127.222     link#6             UHRLWI          0       60     en0     10
17.155.127.223     link#6             UHRLWIi         2       30     en0     10
127                localhost          UCS             0        0     lo0
localhost          localhost          UH              3   235135     lo0
169.254            link#6             UCS             3        0     en0
rivera.local       link#6             UHLSW           1        1     en0
iphone-2.local     b4:18:d1:5b:57:98  UHLSW           1       10     en0   1195
169.254.185.223/32 link#6             UCS             0        0     en0
169.254.255.255    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWb           0       23     en0

Internet6:
Destination        Gateway            Flags         Netif Expire
::                 link#6             UC              en0
default            tun0               USc            tun0
::                 fe80::62f8:1dff:fe UcI            tun0
localhost          localhost          UHL             lo0
::ffff:10.0.0.1    link#15            UHL             lo0
::ffff:10.0.0.1    link#6             UHLWI           en0
rivera.local       60:f8:1d:cc:24:14  UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0         fe80::1%lo0        UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0        link#1             UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en0         link#6             UCI             en0
iphone-2.local     b4:18:d1:5b:57:98  UHLWIi          en0
rivera.local       60:f8:1d:cc:24:14  UHLI            lo0
fe80::%tun0        fe80::62f8:1dff:fe UcI            tun0
fe80::62f8:1dff:fe link#15            UHLI            lo0
fe80::%utun0       fe80::4570:eb3:1c6 UcI           utun0
fe80::4570:eb3:1c6 link#16            UHLI            lo0
ff01::%lo0         localhost          UmCI            lo0
ff01::%en0         link#6             UmCI            en0
ff01::%en6         link#11            UmCI            en6
ff01::%tun0        fe80::62f8:1dff:fe UmCI           tun0
ff01::%utun0       fe80::4570:eb3:1c6 UmCI          utun0
ff02::%lo0         localhost          UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en0         link#6             UmCI            en0
ff02::%en6         link#11            UmCI            en6
ff02::%tun0        fe80::62f8:1dff:fe UmCI           tun0
ff02::%utun0       fe80::4570:eb3:1c6 UmCI          utun0
```

I have the DNS server specified under System Preferences -> Network (8.8.8.8), however running `$ scutil --dns` doesn't show anything for `resolver #1`

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  order    : 301000
```

Can someone tell me why DNS wouldn't be working?